# how can i run a php command from the prompt?

Tags: php

I installed the Lighttpd server with php according to this tutorial:
http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/light-webserver

the command to install php was this:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-common php5-cgi php5
```

What i would like to do is to run the php commands from the prompt, and not only via lighttpd, and i thought i heard somebody say that you could also do this:

```
php testme.php
```

now i get an invalid command error, and I think that is because the php executable can not be found?

Then I've looked where the PHP package was installed, <strike>but I can not find it</strike> I don't know how to find it.

For Python it was easy because i could call that from every path, but I can not do that for PHP.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install "php5-cli":

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

After that, you will have a `php` binary to run in your path. You can see where it is with:

```
which php
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that. Can you explain me what you mean by 'php binary to run in your path'? Does the install of 'php5-cli' only set the path correct, or does it install an extra binary for running PHP from the prompt, or.....

Comment: When you type "php" (or "ls" or anything), it checks the variable $PATH to see the folders where to look for the "php"/"ls"/... binary. (you can see this by typing "echo $PATH") After installing php5-cli, the "php" will be in one of the folders inside $PATH, so you can just run it by typing "php <somescript.php>", and do not need to know a full path for that binary.

Comment: So it's more a settings kind of install than an extra program installed? If I would know the location of the installed PHP libs, then i could run php from the prompt also without installing the php5-cli? (Not that I don't want to install the php5-cli, just trying to understand)

Comment: No, you still need php5-cli (since the binary is in that package). If you install a custom package ("mybin"), you can install the binary to /some/random/path/, but if you wish to run it, you must run it with full path ("$ /some/random/path/mybin"). If "/some/random/path" is in the $PATH variable, you can run it just with "$ mybin". Since php5-cli installs itself in a folder which is inside the default $PATH variable, you can run it just via "php5" or "php" (not sure), without thinking about where the binary is ("/usr/bin" or "/usr/local/bin" or wherever)

Comment: Feeling stupid that i still don't understand :-( Is there not already a PHP binary when i installed `sudo apt-get install php5-common php5-cgi php5`? Because I can run php via Lighthttpd? Or is that a binary which can not be run on the prompt?

Comment: That is a library for apache/lighthttpd/etc. You need a standalone binary to run php scripts from cli.